# Kivy background in scroll view

Tags: python, kivy

*Summary of test application:* I am writing a Kivy app with a scrollable view (named `Scroller`) with many fields (named `Field`) to look at. These separate fields are really difficult to distinguish on occasion, so I decided to use alternating background colors for each field to help distinguish each other. My testing application uses 20 individual fields each of which alternates between dark grey and darker grey.

*Testing trials:*
Starting the application, the program looks great. The alternating background appear just fine. Even when I scroll down the application looks fine. However, the application seems to get bizarre when I scroll up on the application. The text scrolls with the application, but the background does not. Even better (sarcastically), the text starts to fade away into their neighbors background. The problem just seems to vanish when I scroll down again (passed the point of the furthest scroll up point).

*Brief problem description*: The `Field`'s "background color" messes up the application during scrolling up events.

*Side note:* I have also noticed that the application got a little sluggish after scrolling too much. I am not that familiar with the drawing cycle of Kivy, but blitting backgrounds should not yield an excessive slowdown.

*Testing application:*

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = GridLayout(rows = 1)
        self.root.add_widget(Scroller())
        return self.root

class Scroller(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self):
        ScrollView.__init__(self)
        self.view = GridLayout(cols = 1, size_hint = (1, None))
        self.add_widget(self.view)
        self.view.bind(minimum_height = self.view.setter('height'))

        for i in range(20):
            self.view.add_widget(Field('Test field {}'.format(i),i%2 is 0))

class Field(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, name, bg):
        assert isinstance(name, str)
        assert isinstance(bg, bool)
        self.bg = bg
        GridLayout.__init__(self,
                            rows = 1,
                            padding = 10,
                            size = (0, 60),
                            size_hint = (1, None))
        self.add_widget(Label(text = name))
        self.add_widget(Button(text = 'Test button',
                               size = (200, 0),
                               size_hint = (None, 1)))
        self.bind(pos = self.change_background)
        self.bind(size = self.change_background)

    def change_background(self, *args):
        with self.canvas.before:
            if self.bg:
                Color(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, mode = 'rgb')
            else:
                Color(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, mode = 'rgb')
            Rectangle(pos = self.pos, size = self.size)

if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    app = Main()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def change_background(self, *args):
        self.canvas.before.clear()#<- clear previous instructions
        with self.canvas.before:
            if self.bg:
                Color(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, mode = 'rgb')
            else:
                Color(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, mode = 'rgb')
            Rectangle(pos = self.pos, size = self.size)
```

You are adding/piling instructions  to the canvas every time the Field's position/size changes, without clearing the previous instructions.

You should also look into using kv as for anything more than a small snippet it ends up saving you a lot of time. You can convert you code using kv like so ::

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Scroller>
    # root is Scroller here
    # create a new ObjectProperty in kv that holds the ref to Gridlayout
    # so you can access the instance in python code
    view: glayout
    GridLayout:
        id: glayout
        cols: 1
        size_hint: (1, None)
        height: self.minimum_height

<Field>
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1) if self.bg else (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            # binding properties is done implicitly and instructions aren't
            # piled up while doing that.
            pos: self.pos
            # self here refers to Field as `self` is supposed to refer to the
            # Widget not the drawing instruction
            size: self.size
    rows: 1
    padding: 10
    size: (0, 60)
    size_hint: (1, None)
    Label:
        text: root.name
    Button:
        text: 'test button'
        size: (200, 0)
        size_hint: (None, 1)
''')


class Main(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = GridLayout(rows = 1)
        self.root.add_widget(Scroller())
        return self.root


class Scroller(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scroller, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(20):
            # access self.view that was set in kv
            self.view.add_widget(
                                Field(
                                    name = 'Test field {}'.format(i),
                                    bg = i%2 is 0))

class Field(GridLayout):

    # use  kivy's Properties so it becomes easier to observe and apply changes
    # as a plus these can also be directly used in kv. As a advantage of using this now
    # you can change name and bg dynamically and the changes should be reflected on
    # screen
    name = ObjectProperty('Test field uninitialized')

    bg = BooleanProperty(False)


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    app = Main()
    app.run()
```