# Python Kivy Adding ScrollView to Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Note: I am using code from [another discussion on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016350/kivy-background-in-scroll-view).

This code works well in the original way it was written, and returns a layout with the proper widget(s):

[image: Original Code Result]

However, once I add screens using this method:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TestScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        layout.add_widget(Scroller())
        TestScreen().add_widget(layout)
        MyScreenManager().add_widget(screen=TestScreen(name='TestScreen'))

        return MyScreenManager()


class Scroller(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self):
        ScrollView.__init__(self)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint=(1, None))
        self.add_widget(layout)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        for i in range(20):
            layout.add_widget(Field('Test field {}'.format(i), i%2 is 0))


class Field(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, name, bg):
        assert isinstance(name, str)
        assert isinstance(bg, bool)
        self.bg = bg
        GridLayout.__init__(self,
                            rows = 1,
                            padding = 10,
                            size = (0, 60),
                            size_hint = (1, None))
        self.add_widget(Label(text = name))
        self.add_widget(Button(text = 'Test',
                               size = (200, 0),
                               size_hint = (None, 1)))
        self.bind(pos = self.change_background)
        self.bind(size = self.change_background)

    def change_background(self, *args):
        self.canvas.before.clear()
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(.4, .4, .4, mode='rgb')
            Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

Main().run
```

I end up with something that looks like this:

[image: Result of code after screens]

if anyone could help me, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The black/blank window was due to the fact, TestScreen() and MyScreenManager() were not instantiated.

```
class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        layout.add_widget(Scroller())
        testscreen = TestScreen(name='TestScreen')
        testscreen.add_widget(layout)
        root = MyScreenManager()
        root.add_widget(screen=testscreen)
        return root
```

## Output

[image: Img01]